# I want to redirect the user from http to https the problem here it redirects but i am not able to see my site, it's all blank even though it redirects

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, backend

example:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    location / {
    root /var/app/current/public/index.html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

My question is, I am using aws elasticBeanStalk. I want to redirect the user from http to
https the problem here is being redirect but i am not able to see my site
or react app.

`getter error 500 internal server error from nginx`

if i change from

`root /var/app/current/public/index.html;`

to

`root /var/app/current/public;`

nothing appears in when i hit example.com

Comment: Do you have an internet gateway in front of your elastic beanstalk? Does your security group allow public access in both the HTTP port (80) and HTTPs (443) ports?